# How to resolve 500 Internal Server Error Bot framework (C# SDK) on Windows Server 2016/2012r2

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I deployed my bot to Windows Server 2016 with IIS 10. It starts fine but after few messages it starts giving my Internal Server 500. When I run it on my local computers IIS it works perfectly fine. I am using .Net version 4.6 on both Server and local computer. I am not sure why is this happening?

I tried it on windows server 2012r2 and IIS 8, it gives same inetranl server error 500 after few message exchanges.

Here is some detail about error.

```
Faulting application name: botframework-emulator.exe, version: 3.5.31.0, time stamp: 0x596d1933
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18725, time stamp: 0x59380775
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000035690
Faulting process id: 0x15a8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3168d86f3c274
Faulting application path: C:\Users\muhammad\AppData\Local\botframework\app-3.5.31\botframework-emulator.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: f48b02d4-8280-11e7-80ce-000c29837137
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Following is the image of error in the emulator.
[image: InternaServerError]

Comment: is this random or always happening at the same point after x amount of messages?

Comment: @JasonSowers, Mostly it happens after 4 or 5 message exchanges. And some times it starts to work again and then after 2 or 3 messages again 500 internal server error

Comment: Is there some specific configuration need to be done on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Your bot's `/api/messages` endpoint must be served over `https` with a valid SSL certificate in order to work with the Bot Connector service.

Comment: For testing in emulator you don't need SSL